# Convert for loop to apply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

In R, how do you replace the following code using functions like `apply`, `lapply`, `rapply`, `do.call`, etc.?

```
u <- 10:12
slist <- list()

for (i in 1:length(u)) {
  p <- combn(u, i) 
  for (j in 1:ncol(p)) {
    s <- paste(p[,j], collapse=",")
    slist[[s]] <- 0
  }
}
```

For this part:

```
  for (j in 1:ncol(p)) {
    s <- paste(p[,j], collapse=",")
```

I tried something like:

```
  s <- apply(p, 2, function(x) paste(x, collapse=","))
```

Which works. But then for that `slist[[s]] <- 0` part inside that same for-loop, I don't know what to do.

**Edit:** This is what I'm trying to do. For the vector `u`, I'm producing a list of all the subsets in that vector. Then for each subset, I'm assigning it to `s`, then using the string `s` as the name of an element in `slist`. Kind of strange, I know, but it's for a homework assignment. For the code above, this would be the first 5 elements of slist:

```
 > slist
 $`10`
 [1] 0

 $`11`
 [1] 0

 $`12`
 [1] 0

 $`10,11`
 [1] 0

 $`10,12`
 [1] 0
```

Yeah, I'm just trying to learn how to use apply and stuff properly.

Comment: Your `for` loop produces a rather unusual list.  Perhaps you want to explain what it is you are really trying to do?

Comment: Okay, done! I edited the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
n <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(u), function(i) {
  apply(combn(length(u),i),2, function(x) paste(u[x], collapse=','))
}
))

slist <- list()
slist[n] <- 0
```

**UPDATE** Posted at the same time as @djhurio, it is very similar, but I took the liberty of changing the use of `combn` so it handles `u` of length 1, as @djhurio pointed out.

Comment: Can I get any rep for increasing the use of *apply's by one? `indvec <- unlist(lapply( sapply(1:3, combn, x=u) , function(z) apply(z, 2, paste, collapse=",") ) )`

Comment: Well, you got a comment upvote from me - Then complain to the stackoverflow maintainers that comment upvotes should give rep points ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Solution using one `apply` and one `lapply`. Works also if `length(u)==1`.

```
# Define function to create combinations
f1 <- function(y, i) {
  if (length(y)==1) as.character(y) else {
    p <- combn(y, i)
    apply(p, 2, function(x) paste(x, collapse=","))
  }
}

# Initial vector
u <- 10:12

# Character vector with all posible combinations
l <- unlist(lapply(1:length(u), f1, y=u))
l

# Create list with 0 values and same length as l
slist <- as.list(rep(0, length(l)))

# Assign names to the list objects
names(slist) <- l

slist
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without the need for anonymous functions. The `mapply` vectorizes `combn`, while `rapply` traverses the combination list recursively, collapsing them using `,`.

```
rapply(mapply(combn, list(u), seq_along(u), simplify = F), paste, collapse = ",")
```