# Going from a for loop to a function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, apply, levels

I'm curious how I could convert a for loop that I've written into a function in R? I've no experience with writing my own functions in R. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142362/convert-for-loop-to-apply) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407610/r-how-to-turn-a-loop-to-a-function-in-r) but these did not seem to offer much help. I am aware that for loops are not necessary and overall I'm trying to do something similar to [this blog post](https://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/r-apply-function-no-need-for-loops/).

The for loop with reproducible data is here:

```
P <- c(1:50)
y <- length(P)
D <- as.data.frame(combs(P,2))
Z <- choose(y,2)
Num = NULL
Denom = NULL
Diff = NULL

for(n in 1:Z)
   {
    Num[n] = abs(D$V1[n]-D$V2[n])
    Denom[n] = max(D$V1[n], D$V2[n])
    Diff[n] = Num[n]/Denom[n]
    }
 PV=mean(Diff)
 PV
```

But, I'm interested in calculating PV based on levels such as in this data:

```
DATA <- c(1:500)
NAME <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
mydf <- as.data.frame(cbind(DATA, NAME))
```

Therefore, my final code I would like to use would be:

```
ANSWER <- tapply(mydf$DATA, mydf$NAME, MY.FUNCTION)
```

So, if I could turn the above for loop into a working function I could run the tapply function to get PV based on levels.

Any help would be appreciated or any other suggestions opposed to the one I offer.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: The expected outcome would be using the function in tapply. I would want the function to return PV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your library loaded:

```
library(caTools)
```

Here's a function you can run on your data:

```
mymeandiff <- function(values){
    df <- as.data.frame(combs(values, 2))
    diff <- abs(df$V1 - df$V2)/pmax(df$V1, df$V2)
    mean(diff)
}
mymeandiff(1:50)
```

Then we can use `dplyr` to run on each group (after correcting the data):

```
mydf$DATA <-as.numeric(as.character(mydf$DATA))

library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(NAME) %>%
         summarise(mymeandiff(DATA))
```

For apply, rather than dplyr:

```
tapply(mydf$DATA, mydf$NAME, FUN = mymeandiff)
```

Let's time it:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tapply = tapply(mydf$DATA, mydf$NAME, FUN=mymeandiff),
                               dplyr = mydf %>% group_by(NAME) %>%
                                                summarise(mymeandiff(DATA)))
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 tapply 60.36543 61.08658 63.81995 62.61182 66.13671  80.37819   100
  dplyr 61.84766 62.53751 67.33161 63.61270 67.58688 287.78364   100
```

`tapply` is slightly faster

Comment: Both of those work and provide the same result as my for loop. But I'm interested in how I would calculate PV for various levels. Such as in this data    DATA <- c(1:500)
    NAME <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
    mydf <- as.data.frame(cbind(DATA, NAME)).

Comment: Thanks! Precisely what I was looking for. Appreciate the help!